# Found '0' definitions of operator "=", cannot determine exact overloaded matching definition for "="

Tags: vector, vhdl

When i want to check syntax in simulation i have this error. 
"Line 105: found '0' definitions of operator "=", cannot determine exact overloaded matching definition for "=" "
I tried to add libraries as others said in others similar threads but it didnt help. This is my code, and my libraries used:

```
    library IEEE;
    use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
    use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_ARITH.ALL;
    use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;
    use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;
  -- Uncomment the following library declaration if using
  -- arithmetic functions with Signed or Unsigned values
  --use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;

  -- Uncomment the following library declaration if instantiating
  -- any Xilinx primitives in this code.
  --library UNISIM;
  --use UNISIM.VComponents.all;

entity multiwib is

port(trigger : in std_logic;
      reset   : in std_logic;
      CLK     : in std_logic;
      led     : out std_logic
      );

end multiwib;

architecture multiwib_arch of multiwib is
type stany is (stabilny,niestabilny);
 signal stan, stan_nast : stany;
signal licztakty : std_logic_vector(25 downto 0);
signal flaga : std_logic;

begin

reg:process(clk,reset)
begin
    if(reset='1')then
        stan<=stabilny;
    elsif(clk'event and clk='1')then
        stan<=stan_nast;
    end if;
end process reg;


multi:process(clk,trigger)
begin

stan_nast<=stan;

case stan is
      when stabilny=>
             flaga<='0';
             led<='0';
             licztakty<=(others=>'0');

             if(trigger='1')then
             stan<=niestabilny;
             led<='1';
             end if;

        when niestabilny=>

                 if flaga ='1' then

                      stan<=stabilny;
                else 
                      stan<=niestabilny;
                 end if;



 end case;

end process multi;
```

licznik:process(clk,reset)
    begin

```
    if reset ='1' then
            licztakty<=(others=>'0');
    elsif(clk'event and clk='1') then
            if(stan=niestabilny) then
                licztakty<=licztakty+"01";
                led<='1';
            elsif(stan=niestabilny and licztakty="?10111110101111000010000000?")then
               flaga<='1';
            elsif(stan=stabilny) then
                    licztakty<=(others=>'0');
            end if;

    end if;

end process licznik;

end multiwib_arch;
```

Comment: I did not count, but  I don't think there is a line 105 in the code above. Also for this sort of error in VHDL, it is essential that we know  all the types of the variables in the line(s) that cause it. I see only the type of `licztakty`.

Comment: Because this isnt all of te code i have, but the line with error is that line with licztakty="‭10111110101111000010000000‬", now there is all of my code i wrote

Comment: You should add to that the question: The error is in the line.... Also ( I rarely use VHDL) have you checked the operator precedence, especially of '=' and 'and'?

Comment: That helps a lot ;)

Comment: Your actual 'libraries used' are `std` (made visible by an implicit library clause) and `ieee`. Your actual packages  used are `ieee.std_logic_1164` and `ieee.std_logic_unsigned` (from Synopsys and not part of the standard, uses `ieee.std_logic_unsigned."+"` to add two std_logic_vector values).

Comment: Because the length of the string literal with the question marks removed matches the length of the first parameter (`licztakty="‭10111110101111000010000000‬"`) it appears you've suffered from a transcription error introducing extraneous '?' characters. Note that every declaration in VHDL is unique. The declaration of type unsigned used in package std_logic_unsigned (from std_logic_arith) is not the same type as that found in package numeric_std. The two types are incompatible.

Comment: The error is found in IEEE Std 1976-2008 9.3.2 Literals para 5 "String and bit string literals are representations of one-dimensional arrays of characters. The type of a string or bit string literal shall be determinable solely from the context in which the literal appears, excluding the literal itself but using the fact that the type of the literal shall be a one-dimensional array of a character type. ..." The '?' characters are not of the element base type of `licztakty`, where std_logic_vector is a one-dimensional array with a character element base type without '?' as an enumeration value.

Answer (score 0):

You have written `licztakty="?10111110101111000010000000?"` .

licztakty is a std_logic_vector and ? is not a valid std_logic value. valid options are `'U', 'X', '0', '1', 'Z', 'W', 'L', 'H', '-'`

'?' makes the compile try and compare std_logic_vector to a string, and I assume you havent written a custom '=' function for the compare.

Comment: Yes its mistake, but when i write there 0 or 1 the problem remains. If i use vector 3 downto 0 it works, but when it is bigger it doesnt.

Comment: IEEE Std 1076-2008 9.2.3 Relational operators para 4 "Two composite values of the same type are equal if and only if for each element of the left operand there is a matching element of the right operand and vice versa, and the values of matching elements are equal, as given by the predefined equality operator for the element type...." Simply removing the question marks would give you a string literal of length 26 (matching licztakty'length). You haven't defined what works or not in your question, instead providing semantically invalid code that fails to analyze.